# DirectShow Sample Grabber being called but 'this' in callback is NULL

Tags: c++, windows, webcam, directshow, samplegrabber

I'm working on a basic implementation of a DirectShow filtergraph to get images
from my webcam in my application. I've read the documentation and created a simple
implementation. I create this graph: device --> samplegrabber -> nullrenderer.

I'm checking all the result values I possibly can and I get no errors form the SDK.

**The problem:**

Somehow my callback is being called correctly, but whenever I add any code inside
the callback functions (this counts for both SampleCB and BufferCB) my application 
crashes silently.

I've added a breakpoint in my BufferCB and I see that 'this' is 0x0000000 / NULL. 
Because I check all the result values when I create my graph, my guess is that my 
graph setup is correct and that this problem could be related to COM.. but this is
just a wild guess.

Because the Windows 7.0 SDK does not provide a qedit.h, which contains the interface
for the ISampleGrabber interface, I created this file myself and added the relevant 
interface (I found the contents somewhere on a post while googling).

I copied the saveGraph function from the documentation so I could test the graph in 
GraphEdit. When I add a render node, I see that automatically a color conversion
node is edit by GraphEdit. When I run the graph with a renderer I can see the images
from the webcam (in graphedit).

[I've pasted all relevat code in this gist (with a callstack trace + variables)](https://gist.github.com/df1dd70463d78a9fdc55)

Does someone have any idea how I can debug this or what this error might be? Could it
be COM related?

**Update: callstack when trying to access a member in my** `ISampleGrabberCB`

```
ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes  
ntdll.dll!_ZwRaiseException@12()  + 0x12 bytes  
msvcr100d.dll!__lock_fhandle(int fh)  Line 467  C
qedit.dll!CSampleGrabber::Receive()  + 0x18c bytes  
qedit.dll!CTransformInputPin::Receive()  + 0x33 bytes   
quartz.dll!CBaseOutputPin::Deliver()  + 0x22 bytes  
quartz.dll!CVideoTransformFilter::Receive()  + 0x1aa bytes  
quartz.dll!CTransformInputPin::Receive()  + 0x33 bytes  
quartz.dll!CBaseInputPin::ReceiveMultiple()  + 0x33 bytes   
qcap.dll!COutputQueue::ThreadProc()  + 0x103 bytes  
qcap.dll!COutputQueue::InitialThreadProc()  + 0x16 bytes    
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Thanks

Comment: That's way too much code to go through. And way too many `(void**)&something` to understand what pointers it uses.

Comment: How do you define `ISampleGrabberCB` after all? If you defined it incorrectly, the symptom will be exactly as you are having. Here is how you need to do it: http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/ConfigureVideoResizerDmo/ConfigureVideoResizerDmo.cpp?rev=84#L20

Comment: Roman R, thanks, this is how I have defined it: https://gist.github.com/687700c5ac58067db0ba I'm going to try to use the one you pasted

Comment: Your missing `__stdcall` AKA `STDMETHODCALLTYPE` - this is the cause.

Comment: Roman R, you're the best! I added "STDMETHODCALLTYPE" for both SampleCB and BufferCB and now 'this' is not NULL anymore. Going to read up on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since qedit.h is no longer on Windows SDK you have to get definition of Sample Grabber related interfaces. One method is to use older SDK with all headers still on it. Another method is to `#import` the interfaces from type library. And you can always re-defined them right in code.

You can grab the correct definition from [there](http://www.alax.info/trac/public/browser/trunk/Utilities/ConfigureVideoResizerDmo/ConfigureVideoResizerDmo.cpp?rev=84#L20):

```
struct __declspec(uuid("0579154a-2b53-4994-b0d0-e773148eff85"))
ISampleGrabberCB : IUnknown
{
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall SampleCB (double SampleTime, struct IMediaSample * pSample ) = 0;
  virtual HRESULT __stdcall BufferCB (double SampleTime, unsigned char * pBuffer, long BufferLen ) = 0;
};
```

Because you did not have `__stdcall` on yours, the wrong calling convention was used and your `this` was `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

It's very unlikely that this problem is related to COM only. You suggest that COM seems somehow to call your callback interface whereas it's eventaully `NULL`. But if that was the case you'd see the crash even without adding any code to your callback implementation.

As you probably know, all the interface functions in COM are `virtual`. Calling such a function involves first dereferencing the interface pointer and reading the contents of the appropriate `vtable` entry. Hence calling `virtual` function on a `NULL` interface pointer immediately causes an access violation. OTOH calling a non-virtual function on `NULL` object is ok (at least from the implementation point of view, leaving the C++ standard aside).

I suggest you look at the callstack carefully. I believe the COM method is invoked correctly. However in your specific sample you may not implement the COM callback method directly, instead it may be called by some wrapper code (it's very likely for DirectShow library). You should look for the problem there.

Comment: Hi valdo, thanks for your reply. When I try to to use a member in my ISampleGrabberCB class, it crashes with the call stack as pasted in the question above.  I'm not sure why that crashes.